# Power gain of amplifier

Tags: bjt

For power gain , we simply could do like this output power/input power in an amplifier, then what is the reason behind taking logarithm of it making it into decibel? Is there any advantage or is it just a convention?

Comment: This sounds like you understand what decibel is, and what the advantages of using decibel are. Is that correct?

Comment: Sometimes it makes calculations easier. Especially RF link budget calculations.

Comment: @mkeith can you give an example?

Comment: search "link budget calculation."

Comment: What type of amplifier are you referring to - in many cases, we are not particularly interested in power gain.

Comment: Losses in a cable are dB per foot. If it was gain per foot, you would have to calculate, for example, 0.9 W/W ^ 10. But if it is 0.2 dB per foot, then it is just 2 dB in 10 feet. Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several good reasons for using Decibels (or logarithmic ratios for measurements) are:

Dynamic range-using logarithms caters for the potentially large ranges e.g. of gains in electronics. 30 Decibels is a 1000x increase in a quantity.

The gain of isolated circuits can be evaluated simply by adding their gains in dB (multiplicative property of logarithms).

Quantities that decrease or increase rapidly are represented by linear changes in the logarithmic domain e.g. simple first-order network such as a RC circuit will have a roll-off of 20 dB/decade.

You are correct that it is just a convention but it has useful properties.